# How to set Django forms with initial values from request.GET? (with mixed data types)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django form that has both  `CharFields` as well `ChoiceFields`. The form uses `HTTP GET`.

The issue I am having is that `request.GET.dict()` only contains one value for each key, regardless of if the data is a list or not. I discovered that I can use `request.GET.getlist()` to get the all the data but it will return a list even if the item is not a list. This is problematic because it causes the `CharFields` to have the value `[u'']`

What is the recommended way of solving the problem?

My current kludge is the following:

```
initial_dict = {k: v for k, v in request.GET.iterlists()}
clean_dict = {}
for key, value in initial_dict.iteritems():
    if value[0] == '':
        clean_dict[key] = ''
    elif len(value) == 1:
        clean_dict[key] = value[0]
    else:
        clean_dict[key] = value
SellerSearchForm(initial=clean_dict)
```

But I can't beleve that this is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I myself had this issue as well as I wanted to be able to create links for (partial) prefilled forms. I ended up creating a Mixin class for my forms that overrides the `get_initial_for_field()` method ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c6d32e0b233bc44eb4533f81819353036ae35e4/django/forms/forms.py#L484)).

```
class InitialFromGETMixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, initial_from_get=False, **kwargs):
        super(InitialFromGETMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial_from_get = initial_from_get

    def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
        """
        Special implementation of initial gathering if initial values are given through request GET object
        """
        if self.initial_from_get:
            value = self.initial.get(field_name)
            if value is not None:
                return value[0] if len(value) == 1 else value
            else:
                return field.initial
        return super(InitialFromGETMixin, self).get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)
```

This way at least the form is responsible for translating the initial keys to readable forms in a similar way it does with the data attribute. But other than that, there is no better alternative as the form class does not assume initial data to be supplied in the structure request.GET stores the information.